# How to get specific fields in json response from REST api of sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

I have used angularjs to query for data through listData.svc. A json response is returned. May someone suggest how to get the value of a specific field with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
    //get item property
    var fieldValue= result[FieldName];
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking so I will give a broad set of answers.

1. All field names are ***based*** on their display titles, not the Internal Name.
2. If you only want the value of specific fields to be returned you use `$select=` followed by the field names. The following example will return only the values of the fields I specify in the query string and the item's `__metadata` which is always returned with a query.

`../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList?$select=Title,Destription,Created,CreatedBy`

3.  Complex fields such as lookups (including users whose values are lookups to items in the `UserInformationList`) need to be specified in the query string using `$expand=` For example if I am looking at a task list with a field called "Assigned to" I would specify my URL as follows:

`../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyTaskList?$select=Title,Destription,Created,CreatedBy,StartDate,DueDate,AssignedTo&$expand=CreatedBy,AssignedTo`

This would give me a full object graph of the CreatedBy (internal name `Author`) and `AssignedTo` fields. Fields that are shown in dropdowns or radio/check boxes in the standard SP UI generally have their values encoded in their object's `Value` field. Using the example of a task list again I would look for the item's priority in the `PriorityValue` field or if I chose to expand the object it would be in `Priority.Value`.